# Unordered list created by listview not showing on hover

Tags: asp.net, css, listview, hover

I have a navigationbar that's controled completly by css ul and li.

The first unordered list contains listitems which are always displayed (General Site pages). 
on hovering over the listitem (Gamma), the sublistitems appear. These sublistitems are themself in an unordered list of car models with the modelname. Hovering one of these items show me a picture of the car in a seperate div.

When I create the list of cars manually all works fine. The car models en their image are shown correctly. 
When I create the unordered list dynamically by a listview. The car names are not shown.

If I place the listview out of the navigation ul. The listview works correct.

I assume it has something to do with the moment that the listview creates the unordered list. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My ASP.net code

```
<nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a class="active" href="Default.aspx">H</a></li>
                        <li><a href="AixamGamma.aspx">Gamma</a>
                             **<asp:ListView ID="lvGamma" runat="server">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <ul>
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </ul>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <li><a href='<%# "AixamGamma.aspx?Model=" + Eval("car.NewCarID").ToString %>' class="sublistitem"  >
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("car.ModelName") %>'></asp:Label></a>
                                        <div class="modeldetail">
                                            <div class="redbox">
                                                <div class="whitebox">
                                                    <div class="container_12">
                                                        <div class="wrapper">
                                                            <div class="grid_5">
                                                                <h3>
                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblModelSlogan" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("car.Slogan") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                </h3>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="grid_3">
                                                                <div class="wrapper">
                                                                    <img src='<%# Eval("image.ImageLocationPath") + Eval("image.ImageFileName")%>' alt='<%# Eval("car.ModelName") %>'
                                                                        class="img-max-h200-w200" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>**
                            *<ul>
                                <li><a href="AixamGamma.aspx#City" class="sublistitem">City</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AixamGamma.aspx#CityS" class="sublistitem">CityS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="sublistitem">Crossline</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="sublistitem">GTO</a>
                                    <div class="modeldetail">
                                        <div class="redbox">
                                            <div class="whitebox">
                                                <div class="container_12">
                                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                                        <div class="grid_5">
                                                            <h2>
                                                                De nieuwe Aixam Gto</h2>
                                                            <p>
                                                                Rijden zonder rijbewijs in een sportief kleedje</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--- image width max 220px --->
                                                        <div class="grid_3">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <img src="images/Sliders/Aixam%20GTO.jpg" alt="Gto" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="sublistitem">Crossover</a></li>
                            </ul>*
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="UnderConstruction.aspx">Tweedehands</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Onderhoud.aspx">Onderhoud/herstelling </a></li>
                        <li><a href="Wetgeving.aspx">Wetgeving</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

the **bold part** doesn't work except when its placed out the navigation list, the *italic part* does

thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I've tested the code with the hard coded unordered list AND the listview together in one item. Removing the hard coded list did the trick....